# How To add DataGridTemplateColumn to FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGrid)) programmatically? Without xaml parsing

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridtemplatecolumn, frameworkelementfactory

I want create a datagrid programmatically like this

```cs
      var element = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGrid));

      if (reflectionInfo.Type.GenericTypeArguments.Count() == 1)
      {
        var subType = reflectionInfo.Type.GenericTypeArguments[0];
        var fields = subType.GetFieldsRecursive("");
        foreach (var field in fields)
        {
          var column = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DataGridTextColumn));

          var bindingCol = new Binding(field.Path);
          bindingCol.Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay;
          bindingCol.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged;
          column.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, bindingCol);
          element.AppendChild(column);
        }
      }

      return element;
```

but that throws an exception:

```
System ArgumentException
  HResult=0x80070057
  Message = The type "DataGridTemplateColumn" must be derived from "FrameworkElement", "FrameworkContentElement" or "Visual3D".
  Source = PresentationFramework
  Stack monitoring:
   for System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory.set_Type(Type value)
   for System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory..ctor(Type type, String name)
   for System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory..ctor(Type type)
```

I know FrameworkElementFactory is deprecated but the easiest way for me.
Is there a solution with FrameworkElementFactory or with Xaml parse to cast into FrameworkElementFactory.

Comment: Hey! Your title and question  appear inconsistent: one is saying "Without XAML parsing" and the other "or with XAML parse". If you go down the parsing route, there is no need to cast back to the Factory, just to the control itself. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for that I just need the FrameworkElementFactory as return Type, if it's necessary internal i can use XAML parsing.